# using oncomplete attribute to load datatable object lists before firing ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a dataTable containing Files info first of all the user upload a file after that the file is added to database and the file infos appears in the dataTable here's my code:

```
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{projectTestManagementMB.handleFileUpload}"  

      oncomplete="projectTestManagementMB.loadFamilyAttachemtsList()"    
       update="familyAttachmentDt" />  

       <p:dataTable id="familyAttachmentDt" var="familyAttachment" value="#
           {projectTestManagementMB.familyAttachmentsList}">  
                                      <p:column headerText="Name">  
                                        <h:outputText value="#{familyAttachment.name}" 
                          />  
                                      </p:column>  

                                        <p:column headerText="Size">  
                                          <h:outputText value="#
                                      {familyAttachment.size}" />  
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:column headerText="Creation Date">  
                                          <h:outputText value="#
                                   {familyAttachment.date}" />  
                                       </p:column>  

                                       <p:column headerText="Options">  

                                      </p:column>  
                                  </p:dataTable>
```

i want to refresh datatable so i used the update attribute pointing on the dataTable  and the oncomplete attribute  to call the loadFamilyAttachemtsList() method :

```
  public void loadFamilyAttachemtsList(){
   System.out.println("loadFamilyAttachemtsList");
   Family family= (Family) selectedNode.getData();
   DataModel.setCurrentFamily(family);
   familyAttachmentList=DataModel.initSelectedFamilyAttachements(family);


     }
```

But this method is never invoked

Any ida will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The oncomplete attribute is used to call a client side javascript function not any method on the server side.

So just call the loadFamilyAttachemtsList method in your handleFileUpload method at the end and that should work.